# Item in array won't increment

Tags: javascript, arrays

If there is a duplicate in an array, I want to increment the value. These are my console log results:

```
this is the map { '1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 2 }
this is the values more than one 4
this is iitem before 4
this is item after 5
this is iitem before 4
this is item after 5
this is the array here [ 1, 4, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 1, 4, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

And the code:

```js
const incrementDuplicate = function(value, arr){
      for(let item of arr){
        if(item.toString() === value.toString()){
          console.log('this is iitem before', item);
          item = item+1;
          console.log('this is item after', item)
        }
      }
      return arr;
    }
    
    
    const uniqueArraySum = function(arr){
      let map = {};
      let newArray = [];
      for(let item of arr){
        if(!map[item]){
          map[item] = 1;
        } else{
          map[item]++;
        }
      }
      console.log('this is the map', map);
    
      for(let item in map){
        if(map[item] !== 1){
          console.log('this is the values more than one', item);
          newArray = incrementDuplicate(item, arr);
          console.log('this is the array here', arr);
        }
      }
      return newArray;
    }


    console.log(uniqueArraySum([1,4,2,3,4]));
```

Comment: You're gonna need to make you question legible if you want an answer. I literally can't even decipher what you are asking.

Comment: What is your question? What's not working? Help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track, basically your idea of creating a dictionary/map of `counts` is the way to go. You just need to reference it while you iterate through the original array to see if the element occurs more than once and therefore needs incrementing:

```js
const incrementDuplicates = arr => {
  let countDict = getCountDict(arr)
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (countDict[arr[i]] > 1) {
      arr[i]++
    }
  }
  return arr
}

const getCountDict = arr => {
  let countDict = {}
  arr.forEach(val => countDict[val] = (countDict[val] || 0) + 1)
  return countDict
}

console.log(incrementDuplicates([1,4,2,3,4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is  that you trying to mutate the array through the iterator variable. In case of primitive values, that won't work, because JS is not support pointers.

So you should do it like this:

```js
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].toString() === value.toString()){
      console.log('this is item before', arr[i]);
      arr[i] = arr[i]+1;
      //or even simpler `arr[i]++`
      console.log('this is item after', arr[i])
    }
}
```